# Redis throws new error everytime i try to fix something

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

So ive been following BenAwads tut idk if the redis syntax he used is outdated now but i ran into a bunch of error trying to fix one thing and i cant move forward without setting up redis properly.
error->TypeError-RedisStore cannot be created wihout the 'new' keyword

```
import session from 'express-session'
import redis from 'redis'
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis'

const RedisStore=connectRedis(session)
    const redisClient=redis.createClient()

    app.use(
        session(
            {
                name:"qid",
                store:new RedisStore({client:redisClient}),
```

my installs
`npm i redis yarn add redis connect-redis express-session yarn add -D @types/redis @types/connect-redis @types/express-session` 
it has been 3 days i have tried almost everything frustated.Stackoverflow is my last resort for help i would be more than thankful if anyone could help me

ive tried a lot of sources from internet nothing works

Comment: Not sure about the tutorial as there are no links to it, but the connect-redis package looked current with recent versions of Redis when I looked at it last week. What version of Redis are you using? Also, what are the error messages your getting?

Comment: video-https://youtu.be/I6ypD7qv3Z8 around 1:45:00 timestamp he uses redis the first error i got was Redisstore cannot be invoked without new keyword i used as mentioned above "connectRedis(session)" and then used new keyword in definning the store property of session and trying to fix that i managed to brin in more errors

Comment: This tutorial is a bit old, not super old, but a bit. It sounds like you might be using differing versions of things. For example, I notice in it GitHub repo Ben uses ioredis while you use node redis. What version of Redis, both the server and of Node Redis, are you using?

Comment: Also, if you could share a repo, that would make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 7.0.0 of `connect-redis`, it is no longer initialized in the way you see in that tutorial (they are using v5.0.0).

See their note on "Migration from v6" at [v7.0.0 release](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/releases/tag/v7.0.0).

So, the correct code would now be (assuming you are using the latest version of `connect-redis`):

```js
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import { createClient } from 'redis'
import RedisStore from 'connect-redis'

const app = express()

// initialize Redis client and connect
const redis = createClient()
redis.connect().catch(console.error)

// initialize store
const redisStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redis,
})

// initialize session storage
app.use(
  session({
    name: 'qid',
    store: redisStore,
    secret: 'itsasecret',
  })
)
```